# webpack Can't resolve 'style'

Tags: npm, webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-loader

I was trying to follow the simple Getting Started from (http://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/).
And I am getting this error when I try to load style.css.

ERROR in ./entry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style' in 'Path to project in my computer'
BREAKING CHANGE: It's no longer allowed to omit the '-loader' suffix when using loaders.
                 You need to specify 'style-loader' instead of 'style'.
 @ ./entry.js 1:0-22

Any ideas ?

I installed css-loader and style-loader locally using mpm as explained in tutorial.
npm install css-loader style-loader

I see node-modules folder created after the installation.

Comment: It sounds like you installed webpack 2.0 and are following the v1 tutorial?

Comment: That is it. Thanks for quick reply. Config file has changed.

Answer (score 10):

For webpack version >=2.0

Update `webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./entry.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
        ]
    }
};
```

Use **{ test: /.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }** instead of { test: /.css$/, loader: "style!css!" }

Answer (score 0):

Tried 'Use { test: /.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" } instead of { test: /.css$/, loader: "style!css!" }' as above but failed, below config works for me:

```
{
    test:/\.css$/,
    loader:'style-loader!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
}
```