# An error occurs when importing css file in webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

I use webpack. I installed style-loader module by command

```
npm install --save-dev style-loader
```

I import css-file like-this:

```
require('style!css!../css/style.css');
```

But when I run webpack by command

```
webpack -w --devtool source-map js/profile.js dist/bundle.js
```

occurs following error:

> ERROR in ./js/profile.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'style' in '/home/default-user/WebstormProjects/practice/webpack/js'
>   BREAKING CHANGE: It's no longer allowed to omit the '-loader' suffix
>   when using loaders.You need to specify 'style-loader' instead of
>   'style',

Comment: BREAKING CHANGE: It's no longer allowed to omit the '-loader' suffix when using loaders.You need to specify 'style-loader' instead of 'style'
Looks like you have to use that approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42196583

Comment: Possible duplicate of [webpack Can't resolve 'style'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42196583/webpack-cant-resolve-style)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. I have just added word "-loader" in importing ccs-file like this:

```
require('style-loader!css-loader!../css/style.css');
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, [Babel](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#automatic-loader-module-name-extension-removed) does not allow loader specification without the suffix `-loader`. So go on and replace `style` and `css` with `style-loader` and `css-loader` respectively.